# Cannot add a foreign key in mysql where a field is a unique index

Tags: mysql

I'm having problem adding a foreign key based on AUTH_ISLE_CODE:

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `AUTH_ACCOUNT` (
  `ACCOUNT_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PASSWORD` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  ...
  `AUTH_ISLE_ID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `AUTH_ISLE_CODE` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'AAAAA',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ACCOUNT_ID`),
  KEY `fk_ACCOUNT_ISLE` (`AUTH_ISLE_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_ACCOUNT_ISLE` FOREIGN KEY (`AUTH_ISLE_ID`) REFERENCES `AUTH_ISLE` (`ISLE_ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=166 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Create Table: CREATE TABLE `AUTH_ISLE` (
  `ISLE_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NAME` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CODE` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'AAAAA',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ISLE_ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `CODE_UNIQUE` (`CODE`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

the error I'm having is:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'masterdata.#sql-73c1_57910' (errno: 150)
```

Is it something about the fact that the two tables have already a relationship with `AUTH_ISLE_ID`

**Edit 1**: the SHOW CREATE TABLE you see is the current situation. I'm trying to add just the constraint to AUTH_ISLE_CODE -> CODE from AUTH_ISLE

Comment: you'd have to create auth_isle BEFORE you do the auth_account - can't add a foreign key to a table/field which doesn't exist yet. or you'd have to temporarily disable FK checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a sequence of queries you are trying to create tables then it will always fail because you are referencing a table `REFERENCES AUTH_ISLE (ISLE_ID)` which is not created yet ,try creating first `AUTH_ISLE` table then create your second table `AUTH_ACCOUNT`,and when  `AUTH_ISLE` is present you can simply reference its columns

```
 CREATE TABLE `AUTH_ISLE` (
  `ISLE_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NAME` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CODE` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'AAAAA',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ISLE_ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `CODE_UNIQUE` (`CODE`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `AUTH_ACCOUNT` (
  `ACCOUNT_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PASSWORD` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUTH_ISLE_ID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `AUTH_ISLE_CODE` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'AAAAA',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ACCOUNT_ID`),
  KEY `fk_ACCOUNT_ISLE` (`AUTH_ISLE_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_ACCOUNT_ISLE` FOREIGN KEY (`AUTH_ISLE_ID`) 
  REFERENCES `AUTH_ISLE` (`ISLE_ID`) 
  ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=166 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/079a90/1)

```
insert into AUTH_ISLE (NAME,CODE) values('Test','Test');
insert into AUTH_ACCOUNT (PASSWORD,AUTH_ISLE_ID,AUTH_ISLE_CODE) 
values('Test',last_insert_id(),'Test');
```

### [Insert Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d12c14/1)

Comment: hi! I added an edit to explain the situation, the problem is in AUTH_ISLE_CODE. I want to have another fk for AUTH_ISLE_CODE -> CODE

Comment: @dierre what is the problem just define your constraint with a unique name